# Unexpected behavior using ctypes with Python

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I've isolated some strange behavior I'm seeing while using ctypes with Python. Clearly I misunderstand some concept and I'm having trouble pinning it down.

Code:

```
from ctypes import *

class dnpControlPacket(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
            ("dir", c_bool),
            ("prm", c_bool),
            ("fcb", c_bool),
            ("fcv", c_bool),
            ("fc0", c_bool),
            ("fc1", c_bool),
            ("fc2", c_bool),
            ("fc3", c_bool)
            ]

class ctrlUnion(Union):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
            ("data", dnpControlPacket),
            ("bits", c_bool * 8),
            ("bytes", c_uint8 * 1)
            ]

ctrl = dnpControlPacket(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
cu = ctrlUnion(ctrl)
print("bit format: %s" % [x for x in cu.bits])
print("byte format: %d" % cu.bytes[0])
```

My goal is to read the data in byte form using the Union (cu). Strangely, the value of the byte is `1` while the individual bits are `'11000000'`. I'd expect the value of the byte to be `192`? i.e.

```
int('11000000', 2)
```

Can someone help show me where I'm going wrong with this?

Comment: You are expecting `c_bool` to only take 1 bit of space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ctypes` `c_bool` is implemented by the C `_Bool` data type (a.k.a `bool` since C99). It occupies the smallest addressable space which is typically 1 byte and is quite similar to `unsigned char`. The difference is that any non-zero assignment is converted to 1 by the compiler. If you want named bits, the closest you get in `ctypes` is a [Bit field](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ctypes.html#bit-fields-in-structures-and-unions)